Snowflake Flatten and transpose
How can I transpose to another table based on the output of flatten function in Snowflake?
Using select * from table(flatten(input => parse_json({ ... }))); gives this format:

Is there an easy way to transpose this without having to enumerate the keys?

I'm trying to make it dynamic as it will come from a DynamoDB export.

Hi - please don't use images, always use editable text, appropriately formatted. Can you update your question to show 1) sample data 2) the result you want to achieve 3) the query you've managed to write so far (not a dummy/template query)?

Would this stored procedure help? https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c
